# Is there a mechanism in C11 for ensuring expected types of negated integer constants?

Tags: c, constants, integer-overflow, c11

I can not find anywhere in the C standard that justifies the following:

```
int n = -0x80000000 // set n to -2^31
```

Assume an implementation where int is 32 bits. The apparent problem is that the integer constant has type unsigned int, as per the table in the committee draft standard at 6.4.4.1 paragraph 5. Then the negation is calculated according to 6.5.3.3 paragraph 3:

> The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

Performing the integer promotions does not change the type (unsigned int stays unsigned int). Then the negative is taken. Since the result retains the promoted type, it is reduced modulo 2^32, producing 2^31 (so the negation has no effect).

Assigning an out of range value to type int is covered by the following:

> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type. 60)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

So, in the end, we get implementation defined behavior when we try to assign a valid int value to an int object (assuming 2's complement with no trap representation).

The following would be standard guaranteed to have the expected result:

```
int n = -(long long)0x80000000 // set n to -2^31
```

So, do you really need to cast up to validly make an in range assignment, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note about  "standard guaranteed to have the expected result" --> recall `int` can be 16-bit.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming a 32 bit int.

Comment: The problem is actually simple, don't use hex to describe values that possibly can become negative. Hex values are a good tool when you want to describe bit patterns, to be used as masks in bit operations and alike. When you want to describe values for signed arithmetic the bit representation should be irrelevant.

Comment: Congratulations, you have found out that your code `int n = -0x80000000` makes no sense. If you write really weird code, you will often trigger really weird C standard behavior as well.

Comment: @Lundin, the point was to confirm my understanding that '-' is unreliable applied to arbitrary integer type arguments, not to write that particular line. And macros using '-' do not constitute "really weird code".

Comment: @Kyle Rather, any operator is unreliable when applied to an unreliable integer type. Integer literals, without any suffix such as L and/or U, may be of arbitrary type (arbitrary size and/or signedness), depending on their value. This is caused by the somewhat obscure methods that the C language uses to pick types for integer literals and not by the unary - operator. Hex literals are particularly nasty: take for example these 3 values on a 16 bit system: 0x00007FFF, 0x00008000, 0x00010000. They will all result in different types: int, unsigned int and long respective.

Comment: as a side note, you might remember (if you have any machine code background the the change a positive number to a negative number simply invert all the bits, then add 1. This is for 2's compliment operations

Comment: the compiler will modify a value, including literals, via `implicit conversion` to the type of the target variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you remark *Assigning an out of range value to type int is covered by the following:* does not apply to

```
unsigned int n = -0x80000000 // set n to -2^31
```

`n` has type `unsigned int` and the value 2^31 is not out of range for 32 bits `unsigned int`.

**EDIT**: since you changed the question and made `n` an `int`, then *3* applies for 32 bit and lesser `int`s and the comment is incorrect for larger `int` types:

> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

**EDIT**: the second code fragment `int n = -(long long)0x80000000 // set n to -2^31` is correct as the value -2147483648 does fit in a 32 bit `int`.

Note that the correct way to initialize `n` to this value is this (assuming 32 bit ints):

```
int n = -2147483647 - 1;  // set n to -2^31
```

This variant is used in the standard headers `<limits.h>` and `<stdint.h>`.  It does not use casts, so the answer to you last question is: no, you do not really need to cast up to validly make an in range assignment for -2^31 to a 32 bit `int`.

Comment: Good catch, that was accidental, I corrected it to type int.

Comment: @Kyle: the second code fragment uses `unsigned int` too.  The computation is different but the result is identical and correct as long as `unsigned int` has at least 32 value bits.

Answer (score 1):

If `INT_MAX` is `0x7fffffff`, then as a hex literal, `0x80000000` has type `unsigned int` or larger, and applying `-` to it is safe. This would not be true for decimal literals. If `INT_MAX` were larger than `0x7fffffff` then the negation would already be safe as `int`.

With the edited question now assigning the result into an object of type `int`, the conversion from an out-of-range value to `int` is implementation-defined. In practice it's always defined as what you want (modular reduction), but this is not guaranteed by the standard. All the standard guarantees is that the implementation has to document how the conversion takes place.

Comment: Yes, applying - is safe, but the question comes in assigning the result to type int.

Comment: My response here didn't make sense without the correction I just made to the question. n is supposed to be of type int, not unsigned int.

Comment: *In practice it's always defined*... not really! Modern compilers perform counter-intuitive optimizations in presence of potential undefined behavior that can make this assumption fail miserably.

Comment: @chqrlie: It's not undefined. It's implementation-defined. As my answer clearly explains. That requires the behavior to be documented and consistent.

Comment: Overflow otoh is undefined, but no overflow happens here. All that happens is an implementation-defined conversion.

Comment: @R., are you aware of a reference in the standard for "implementation-defined" requiring consistency? An implementation can't define the behavior to simply produce a valid result (i.e., not a trap), or something like that?

Comment: @R.: OK, I stand corrected.  My remark may not apply here but does in similar situations where overflow occurs.  *Implementation defined conversion* is almost as much of a pain as *undefined behavior* when trying to write correct code.

Comment: @chqrlie: I would not call it an issue when trying to write merely *correct* code, only when trying to write code portable to intentionally obtuse implementations. At the very least, testing shows that code with implementation-defined behavior does what you expect. And in the case of conversions of out-of-range integer values to signed integer types, there's essentially a single universal definition all practical implementations have agreed on: modular reduction into the range.

Comment: @R..: The one thing that makes the aforementioned conversion "safe" is that there's no other behavior implementations could efficiently substitute while abiding the requirement of deterministic behavior. On the other hand, it's ironic that the Standard mandates a precise behavior in cases where it would add expense to many implementations, but doesn't specify any behavioral constraints in cases which would often be more useful but cheaper (let overflowed `int` computations yield a value which may behave non-deterministically as numbers outside the range of `int`, but w/o other side-effects).

Comment: @supercat: No, it's that traditional implementors all agreed and established an expectation that the conversion be given the obvious, sane definition, and therefore that any newcomer compiler that tried to choose a different definition would be unusable for most practical purposes and thus rejected. This is the exact same type of consensus/established-practice process that should take place in standardization except that it happened outside the standard process because WG14 still wants to pretend ones complement is implementable.

Comment: @R..: Is it any less obvious that sane implementations on two's-complement silent-wraparound hardware should have integer-overflow behavior that is at least somewhat constrained?  The authors of C89 seemed to think so, but some modern compiler writers, not so much.

Comment: @supercat: The spec has always made the distinction that overflow is undefined whereas conversion of out-of-range values is defined (by the implementation). I see no basis for claiming "the authors of C89" intended for overflow to be constrained in its behavior. C89 3.3.6 spells it out clearly: "As with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @R..: Read the rationale for why short unsigned types promote to signed.  A motivating factor in the decision was the behavior of silent-wraparound two's-complement implementations, (which the according to the authors, comprised  *the majority of [then-]current implementations*) in cases where the arithmetic value of the result would be between INT_MAX+1u and UINT_MAX.  Why do you suppose they would have mentioned such a thing if they didn't regard such behavior as being both defined and desirable?

Comment: @R..: The authors of the Standard clearly didn't intend to require any particular behavior on hardware whose overflow semantics might be unpredictable, but that doesn't mean that they intended that overflow should negate the laws of time and causality on hardware which implements 100% predictable and consistent two's-complement silent-wraparound semantics.

Answer (score 1):

> `int n = -(long long)0x80000000`
>
> do you really need to cast up to validly make an in range assignment, or am I missing something?

How about: `int n = -0x80000000LL`;

No cast.

Comment: Good point, but a very similar problem still exists assigning -2^63 to a long long, which can not be avoided like that. One could do -(2^63-1)-1, but still cumbersome. At any rate, the problem is the unreliability of '-', which apparently I am correct in my understanding that it is unreliable.

Comment: That's what you get for designing a programming language in which `-` is an operator, not part of the numeric constant. Lisp: `(- 123)` --- unary minus applied to `123`; `(+ -123 1)` --- add `1` to `-123` constant.  If you have hex, the sign goes after the prefix `#x-FF` ---  `-255` decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `int n = INT_MIN`.

Or if you must `int n = -2147483648` (same as casting to long long).

Mixing hex literals and negative numbers in C is usually a bad idea, since hex literals assume a specific signedness format.

> we get implementation defined behavior when we try to assign a valid int value to an int object

If you are concerned about implementation-defined behavior, then why do you use the naive `int` type and not `int32_t`?

`int` has implementation-defined size and signedness format, which is the root of the problem. `int32_t` is guaranteed to be 32 bits two's complement.

Comment: Thanks, but there are other issues that are difficult because of this issue, this is just a simplified example to point out the question. In those other cases, it is not so easy to get around. For example, a macro that negates an integer type argument is fundamentally unreliable if it is supposed to accept signed types, because of this behavior.

Comment: @Kyle A macro that negates the argument but accepts unsigned types as argument, is indeed flawed and dangerous. Such macros should preferably be rewritten to functions, so there's some increased type safety.

Answer (score 0):

The relative behavior of signed and unsigned types in C is a mess that came about when the C89 Committee tried to formulate rules that would be as consistent as possible with the behavior of pre-existing compilers that were often inconsistent with each other.

There isn't really any portable way to ensure that expressions involving integer constants will work in expected fashion except to manually ensure that they're promoted to a type that's guaranteed big enough to hold all intermediate values; if you don't need anything beyond 64 bits, either "long long" or "unsigned long long" should suffice; values can be forced to those types using a UL or ULL suffix.